# Django Como hago para que despues de un tiempo se cierre la secion del usuario

Tags: python, django

Necesito llevar un control sobre el tiempo que lleva una sesion activa y despues de cierto tiempo de actividad o innactividad esta pida volver a logearse y que si se cierra la ventana esta vuelva
a pedir un loggin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sabiendo el tiempo que deseas que expire la sesión y vuelva a pedir login, agregar en settings:

SESSION_COOKIE_AGE = 600      # 600 segundos = 10 minutos

Para la segunda parte de la pregunta. Si se cierra la ventana vuelva a pedir login:
En settings agregar:

SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE = True

Comment: debo agregarlo dentro de algo o importar algo, o solo con agegarlo en el settings deberia funcionar ?

Comment: Solo agregarlo al settings debe funcionar.